# Error when trying to Map List using Automapper

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, automapper

I need to map `IReadOnlyList<Person>`  to `IReadOnlyList<PersonResponse>` using `Automapper`.

```
IReadOnlyList<Person> personList = await _personRespository.getall();

var t = MyMapper.Mapper.Map<IReadOnlyList<PersonResponse>>(personList );
```

Mapping Class

```
CreateMap<IReadOnlyList<PersonResponse>, IReadOnlyList<Person>>().ReverseMap();
```

The error I get:

> System.TypeLoadException: Method 'get_Item' in type
> 'Proxy_System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList`1[[App.Application.Responses.PersonResponse,
> App.Application, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null]]*34471389*' from assembly 'AutoMapper.Proxies,
> Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=be96cd2c38ef1005'
> does not have an implementation.    at
> System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder.CreateTypeNoLock()    at
> System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder.CreateTypeInfo()

Comment: `CreateMap<PersonResponse, Person>().ReverseMap()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an mapping between `Person` and `PersonResponse`, the concerned element types. Automapper would take care of collections themselves.

```
CreateMap<PersonResponse, Person>().ReverseMap();
```

You can read more Automapper and Collections [here](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Lists-and-arrays.html)